# What's a stepdown fix in a non-precision approach procedure?

Tags: iaps, non-precision-approach

Could someone explain to me what's a stepdown fix in non-precision approaches?

Answer (score 3):

From the [FAA's Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg_4-03-14.pdf):

> **STEPDOWN FIX** − A fix permitting additional descent within a segment of an instrument approach procedure by identifying a point at
>   which a controlling obstacle has been safely overflown.

In other words, a step down fix tells you "you've passed an obstacle, so you can now descend further".